# angular router does not select child state (nested states)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, parent-child

I'm having a problem with a new state I added to our web site.

**Short description**
I have a state (/page)'q.explorer' which contains a button; when clicked it should go to a child state (named 'q.explorer.detail') but it does not. However: in the logging I see that it does try to go to that (/state) and the new url is formatted as defined in the child state.
But still the template and controller that are actually used is the 'parent' which contains the button ...

This may be a little confusing to explain; so I have also added some code in the hope that this will clarify my problem.

The setup looks like this:

```
$stateProvider        
   .state('q', {
       url: '/:locale/app',
       data : { ui: "V2" },
       views: {
           'application' : {template: '<div ui-view=""><page-home-v2></page-home-v2></div>' }
       }, controller: function($scope, $stateParams, siteNavigation) {
           siteNavigation.applyUrlParameters($stateParams);
       }
   }).state('q.explorer', {
       url: '/explorer?:year&:month&:guide',
       template: '<page-explorer-v2></page-explorer-v2>',
       controller: function($scope, $stateParams, siteNavigation) {
           console.log("controller: qlaro.explorer");
           siteNavigation.applyUrlParameters($stateParams);
       }
   }).state('q.explorer.detail', {
       url: '/detail',
       template: '<page-explorer-detail-v2></page-explorer-detail-v2>',
       controller: function($scope, $stateParams, siteNavigation) {
           console.log("controller: qlaro.explorer.detail");
           siteNavigation.applyUrlParameters($stateParams);
       }
   })


angular
    .module('q.components')
    .service('siteNavigation', function($state, $location) {
        var service = this;

        service.applyUrlParameters = function($stateParams) {                
            if (!$stateParams) $stateParams = $state.params;

            console.log('Apply state parameters for state: ' + $state.current.name);
            console.log('URL >> ' + $location.url());
        };
    };
```

Somewhere deep in the template of "q.explorer" there is a button to open the detail view ("q.explorer.detail"). It uses this code:

```
function goToDetail() {
    var ui = $state.current.data.ui;

    if (ui === "V1") { /*...*/ }
    else if (ui === "V2") {
        var params = {
            year: Store.getYear(),
            month: Store.getMonth(),
            locale: Store.getLocale()
        }
        var guide = Store.getActiveSidebarItem();
        if (guide) params.guide = guide.slug;
        console.log("go to explorer: " + params.guide);

        $state.go('q.explorer.detail', params);
    }
    else console.log("Unable to go to state because the ui version is not known.");
}
```

And this is what I see in the console after clicking the link:

```
go to explorer: ebit
controller: q.explorer
Apply state parameters for state: q.explorer.detail
URL >> /nl/app/explorer/detail?year=2015&month=11&guide=ebit
```

As you can see, it uses the controller of the 'parent' iso the child page I want to open. Even though $state.current.name is correct ... Or maybe I should say it does not change from state ...

Any help is welcome.

(PS: We are using Angular 1.4.9)

Comment: As indicated below the problem was a missing ui-view in the parent. So the solution was to edit the template for _'q.explorer'_ to `template: '<div ui-view><page-explorer-v2></page-explorer-v2></div>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using nested states such that `q.explorer.detail` is a child of `q.explorer`. To render the child state's template, you also need a specific `ui-view` where it can be placed into. And this will be searched in the template of the parent state. Getting the console.log() output just means the controllers are instantiated, but that even happens if the template isn't rendered at all.

So check if you have an `ui-view` in the template of the `q.explorer` state. For more details, please see: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

You could also fix this by not making `q.explorer.detail` a child of `q.explorer`. A child state is created as soon as you need the dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

Yoy have to add somewhere in 'q.explorer' state's template entry point for nested view 'q.explorer.detail', otherwise child controller will not be called.

For example:

```
template: '<page-explorer-v2></page-explorer-v2><ui-view></ui-view>',
```

instead of

```
template: '<page-explorer-v2></page-explorer-v2>'
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcpmsuxj/42/

Upd. As @ajaegle mentioned you should to visit official docs page:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views